# Why multi process glfw applications will halt if `glfw.create_window` is executed in the MainProcess?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, glfw

When we have to run a multi-threaded glfw application, the program will halt if `glfw.create_window()` has been called in the MainProcess.

This is basically part of a much bigger code where I cannot change the architecture (including the multiprocessing architecture), but this is the minimal code that can reproduce the bug.

- Operating System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)
- Python Version: 3.6

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import threading, multiprocessing
import glfw

def worker():
    print("[Thread]:", threading.get_ident(), "[Process]:", multiprocessing.current_process())

    glfw.init()
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, 0)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.DOUBLEBUFFER, 0)
    context = glfw.create_window(width=640, height=480, title='Invisible window', monitor=None, share=None)
    print("Window was created successfully!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ## Uncomment the following line to see the program halt with errors:
    # worker()

    np = 10
    processes = [Process(target=worker) for i in range(np)]

    for p in processes:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    print("LET'S WAIT FOR A LONG TIME!")
    import time
    time.sleep(1000)
```

**First**

If I do not call `glfw.create_window` in the main process the code will work fine. But, if I call it before the other processes are started (you may uncomment `# worker()` to see this effect) it will cause the following error (I copied the output only partially):

```sh
...
XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server ":0"
      after 192 requests (192 known processed) with 15 events remaining.
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server ":0"
      after 192 requests (192 known processed) with 15 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server ":0"
...
```

**Second**:
In the case where `# worker()` is still commented, `glfw.init()` must be inside the `worker` function and cannot be called only once globally, i.e. before the `worker` function. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error, it seems to come from XCB, implying that you are running on a UNIX-like operating system with an X11 server.

In the **first** case, what happens is that you initialize GLFW. Then you create processes. On UNIX-like systems, this is done by using the `fork(2)` system call, which makes a perfect copy of the parent process and then runs both the parent and the child. So now the X11 server has *two* different programs talking to it using the same connection and pretending to be the same. As you can imagine, this doesn't work well.

Furthermore a lot of GUI toolkits (including glfw) are *by design* not thread-safe and `multiprocessing` uses a background thread for housekeeping. I don't think that is the problem here, but it could be.

The **second** case is a variation of the first; every process *must* have its own connection to the X-server.

BTW, `glfw.init()` returns a value indicating success or failure. You should definitely check that glfw was initialized successfully before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation of the situation. For the first case, are there any ways to finish the connection of the Main process with the server before we start the child processes? I have tried `glfw.terminate()` but that causes a SegFault.

Comment: I think the best (and maybe only) way is to *only* initialize glfw in the child processes.